# C Char lin1[] = "1234"; PrintF as integer

Tags: arrays, c, printf

So i have this question i have the following code:

```
char lin1[] = "1234";
printf("main(): %d\n", __________); // Sould print 1234 from lin1 as an integer
```

My goal is to use printf to print the lin1 as an integer withou using atoi or strtol.

So the output should be 1234

I've tried

```
printf("main() %d\n", lin1 -'0');
```

but it won't work the solutions should be something similar to it because it's a simple exercise but i'm not seeing it!

Comment: I see two possibilities: `printf("main() %s\n", lin1);` (changing the format specifier to `%s`) and `printf("main() %d\n", 1234);`. There's no way to print from `lin1` string keeping `%d` without actually converting to int. Unless you are supposed to write your own `my_atoi()`

Comment: i can't change the code, i must use lin1 to print 1234 completing the sintax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically just convert to string to a number. I also included a check if the string is really a 4 digit number:

```
char lin1[] = "1234";
printf("main(): %d\n",
     (
          isdigit(lin1[0]) &&
          isdigit(lin1[1]) &&
          isdigit(lin1[2]) &&
          isdigit(lin1[3]) &&
          lin1[4] == '\0'
     ) ? 
          (lin1[0]-'0')*1000 +
          (lin1[1]-'0')*100 +
          (lin1[2]-'0')*10 +
          (lin1[3]-'0')*1 
     : 
           -1
);
```

Note: you should cast a `char` to `unsigned char` for `isdigit` to be super portable. See ex [wiki.sei STR37-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/STR37-C.+Arguments+to+character-handling+functions+must+be+representable+as+an+unsigned+char)

Comment: Thank you very much, that really works and help me a lot and it's easy to understand too

Comment: Clever! That's something I didn't think when I wrote my comment above; anyway it must be said that it works only with a four digits long numeric string, so it would be definitely required a `my_atoi()` conversion function in a real scenario. (I'm not criticizing: I was glad to upvote)

Answer (score 0):

You got the right strategy but you have to do it char by char...

```
char lin1[] = "1234";
int i;

printf("main(): ");
for(i = 0; lin1[i]; i++)
     printf("%d", lin1[i] - '0');
```

Comment: i can't change the already written code to insert the for. it's a little tricky and i don't know how to do it